# Does Ajax block the window while processing the request?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making an ajax request where it may take much time to process the server-end.So I want to show a loading image at the time of request process.But loading image is not being shown while ajax requst.

```
var ref = createAjaxRequest();//Ajax req is created here...
if(ref){
        showLoadingImg();
        ref.open('POST','x.jsp',false);
        ref.onreadystatechange = eventStateChange;
        ref.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ref.setRequestHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        ref.send();
    }
    else{ alert("Your browser does not support this feature");
}
function eventStateChange(){
 if(ref.readyState==4 ){
    //processing response here......
   hideLoadingImg();
 }
}

function showLoadingImg();{
 /* <div id="ajaxLoading">(with background image is in page)
  It is displayed properly when I set display:inline 
  manually through developer tools of a browser.</div>
*/
  document.getElementById('ajaxLoading').style.display='inline';
}
function hideLoadingImg();{
  document.getElementById('ajaxLoading').style.display='none';
}
```

is there anything wrong?

I tried to debug and found that:

1. Though `showLoadingImg()` is called before `open()` method, the loading image is displayed on browser only after `ref.readyState==2`.
2. But unfortunately time gap between `readyState==2` and `readyState==4` is very less, the loading image is immediately hidden.
   Thus user cannot see the loading image...

So, what I am doubting is, doesn't ajax run the script unless it goes to `readyState==2`.

Comment: What's going on in createAjaxRequest? And is there a reason you can't show the image before creating the request, and then hide it if there's an error (or after completion)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks your call to `open` is wrong.
The third argument (boolean) indicates if the request is asynchronous or not.

Consider complete documentation here : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

```
ref.open('POST','x.jsp',true);
```

Should solve your problem.

Regards

Comment: Thank you..you r right.But what if a load image has to shown though ajax call is synchronous?

Answer (score 2):

XMLHttpRequest blocks if you set `async` to `false` as you do with the third argument here: `ref.open('POST','x.jsp',false);`.

Comment: That's what I thought, but OP called showLoadingImg before open, and still had to wait ref.readyState==2 to see the image.

Comment: @grape_mao — It blocks the function from finishing, so it takes some time before the browser runs a DOM paint.

Comment: so in js a function can start execution before the previous one finishes? Or just because here is a DOM operation?

Comment: If function A calls function B, then function B is going to finish before returning control to function A so that function A can continue and finish. The DOM gets changed, but the browser doesn't repaint the DOM immediately, it waits until the thread is free.